# Finding nearest altitude point in a DEM in R

Tags: r, distance, altitude

I'm looking for a function that would allow me to locate the closest distance point of a given altitude from a specified point on a DEM in R. For instance I have a site on the interior Tibetan plateau located at 4500 meters above sea level and I would like to know at what distance the closest 2500 meter above sea level point is located. I'm essentially asking to find the least cost path but I dont know where the point is that I would be asking to go to.

I've checked out the topodistance package, however, this presumes that I already know where the point is and only then allows me to calculate the distance. I've also checked out the leastcostpath package, however, there is an assumption that I must already know the location of the point to be travelled to. Is there a function that will allow me to do an automated search for the nearest low altitude point?

Comment: Do you have a DEM already, or just the chosen point? Welcome to Stackoverflow.

Answer (score 0):

I built a relatively simple function ('*NearAlt*') that can perform this task. It is possible to increase its complexity by considering the slope, path cost, as well as the presence of obstacles. However, if I understood correctly, you already have another solution to take these factors into consideration.

```
# install.packages("raster")
# install.packages("rgdal")
# install.packages("sf")

library(raster)
library(rgdal)
library(sf)


dem <- raster("n28_e082_1arc_v3.tif") # Load your DEM

NearAlt <- function(x, CoordStart, targetAlt) {
  RastDiff <- abs(x - targetAlt) # Difference to target altitude
  
  # Extract the value at the start coordinate
  startDiff <- extract(RastDiff, matrix(c(CoordStart[1], CoordStart[2]), ncol=2))
  
  # Check if is already at the desired altitude
  if (startDiff == 0) {
    return(list(distance = 0, coord = CoordStart))
  }
  
  # Convert the raster to a data frame
  diffMatrix <- as.data.frame(RastDiff, xy=TRUE)
  
  # Find the minimum difference
  cells <- diffMatrix[diffMatrix[3] == min(diffMatrix[3], na.rm = TRUE),]

  # Calculate distances and find the closest
  point_orign <- st_as_sf(data.frame(x = c(CoordStart[1]), y = c(CoordStart[2])), coords = c("x", "y"), crs = crs(x))
  points_destiny <- st_as_sf(data.frame(x = cells[,1], y = cells[,2]), coords = c("x", "y"), crs = crs(x))
  distances <- st_distance(point_orign, points_destiny)
  minDistanceIndex <- which.min(as.integer(distances))
  
  return(list(distance = distances[minDistanceIndex], coord = c(cells[minDistanceIndex,1], cells[minDistanceIndex,2])))
}


CoordStart <- c(82.5367721, 28.8306240) # Replace with your coordinates
targetAlt <- 2500 # Replace with your target altitude

result <- NearAlt(x = dem, CoordStart, targetAlt)
print(paste("Closest distance:", result$distance))
print(paste("Coordinates:", result$coord[1], ",", result$coord[2]))

# Check the reslts
extract_start <- extract(dem, SpatialPoints(matrix(CoordStart, ncol = 2)), sp = T)
extract_destiny <- extract(dem, SpatialPoints(matrix(result$coord, ncol = 2)), sp = T)
alt_start <- extract_start@data$n28_e082_1arc_v3 # Change to match your DEM
alt_destiny <- extract_destiny@data$n28_e082_1arc_v3 # Change to match your DEM

# Tabulate the results
results_df <- data.frame("X" = c(CoordStart[1], result$coord[1]), "Y" = c(CoordStart[2], result$coord[2]), "Altitud"=c(alt_start, alt_destiny), "Position"= c("start", "destiny"))
results_df_points <- SpatialPointsDataFrame(results_df[,1:2], data = results_df, proj4string = crs(dem))

# Write as shapefile
writeOGR(obj=results_df_points, dsn="./results_df_points.shp", layer="torn", driver="ESRI Shapefile")

# Visualize the results
plot(dem)
plot(results_df_points, col="blue", add=T)
```